# C++ How to use a function for another variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

How can I use my function output_integer for the array v, without making a new function? I need to print the values that end up in v, but i want to use the same function as i do for m:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int m[10];
int v[10];
void input_integer()
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Element "<<i+1<<"=";
        cin>>m[i];
    }
}
void output_integer()
{
    cout<<"The values of the array are:\n";
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Element "<<i+1<<" = "<<m[i]<<"\n";
        }
}
void copy_div3()
{
    int k=0;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if (m[i]%3==0)
        {
            v[k]=m[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    //input_integer();
    output_integer();
    copy_div3();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is homework, please add the appropriate tag. This is a very basic question. If you do not know about function parameters, you should get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/), or read a tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

Make the `output_integer` to take the array as parameter, so that you can pass it any array

Answer (score 4):

You can change the function signature to take the array argument and print it, instead of relying on the global-ness of the variable.

```
void output_integer(const int (&arr)[10])
{
  cout<<"The values of the array are:\n";
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    cout<<"Element "<<i+1<<" = "<<arr[i]<<"\n";
  }
}
```

To make it more generic, you can even think of making it a `template`:

```
template<unsigned int SIZE>
void output_integer(const int (&arr)[SIZE]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just provide a pointer to that array and its size:

```
void output_integer_array(int* array, int size)
{
    cout<<"The values of the array are:\n";
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Element "<<i+1<<" = "<<array[i]<<"\n";
        }
}
```

usage:

```
output_integer_array(m, 10);// you may want to store the size as a const variable instead of a magic number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to functions.

Define `output_integer like this:

```
void output_integer(int* array)
{
    cout<<"The values of the array are:\n";
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Element "<<i+1<<" = "<<array[i]<<"\n";
        }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
output_integer(v);
output_integer(m);
```

Actually, it would probably be a good exercise to move the `m` and `v` arrays away from the global scope entirely. Define them only inside the `main` function so that they *have* to be passed as parameters to any function that needs to access them.

Comment: Note: With this approach, `output_integer` is vulnerable to buffer overflow. If `array` size is less than `10`. Moreover, OP is mentioning `using namespace std;`; so argument name `array` may collide with `std::array`.

Comment: @iammilind: true. I wanted to keep it as simple as possible (and use the most descriptive array name possible), since the OP obviously is new to C++. In reality, he shouldn't be using raw arrays at all (either `std::array` or more likely `std::vector`, but again, I tried to keep it simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the basic concept of functions: all logic should depend on parameters passed to the functions (if non-member). You have a free function (not part of the class), so if you need to print an array, you should pass that array as a parameter:

```
void output_integer(const int* m)
{
    cout<<"The values of the array are:\n";
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Element "<<i+1<<" = "<<m[i]<<"\n";
        }
}
```

Since you use c++, I also suggest using `std::vector` instead of arrays:

```
void output_integer(const std::vector<int>& m)
{
    cout<<"The values of the array are:\n";
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Element "<<i+1<<" = "<<m[i]<<"\n";
        }
}
```

When you're done with the changes, google for "magic parameters".

Comment: The concept you are mentioning is actually that of _pure_ functions.